# Why do I have segmentation fault in this if line?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, sockets, if-statement

Recently I was making a program and it was giving me segmentation fault. After using gdb, I realized where I had the problem but I can't solve that.

The function is the following:

```
int readSocket_line(int socket, char * array) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (read(socket, & array[i], 1) < 0) {
            return -1;
            break;
        }
        if ((array[i] == '\n') || (array[i] == ' ')) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

The error that is shown by gdb is the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb3df5b40 (LWP 24457)]
0x08048f70 in readSocket_line (socket=18, array=0xb3df5337 "")
    at sockets_clie.c:14
14            if((array[i] == '\n') || (array[i] == ' ')){
```

I can't understand how can I solve that problem.

I would like some help to solve and understand this error.
Thank you!

Comment: Variable `i` may exceed the memory reserved for `array`. You need to compare `i` to the amount of memory assigned to `array`

Comment: This function needs a lot more error checking to be usable and debuggable. If the function marks the end of received data with a zero, it needs to make sure it doesn't receive a zero. And it needs to know the length of the array and check for out of bounds. You may not need these things once the code is working (but you probably do!) but you definitely need them while you're trying to debug it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Due to my lack of experience I just did realized how bad I had my error checking in the whole program too late (with hundreads of lines of code). To make that verification of i, what do I need to do? (could a bad and fast solution be to increase the size of the array?)

Comment: Pass the size of the array to the function. After the check for newline or space, add a check to see if the array is full or the read character was a zero and, if so, return `-1`. And, of course, learn a valuable lesson about making your code check itself for errors and not proceed blindly to a later point where it's too hard to figure out how you got there.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks again! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault occurs when a program tries to read/write from an illegal location in memory. Your function will keep incrementing the value of i until either a '\n' (newline) or ' ' (space) is found. If neither of those conditions occur, i will keep incrementing and may cause &array[i] to point to a location in memory that is not writeable.

On another note, the name of your function is a bit misleading as usually line endings are marked with a '\n' or '\r' or both. A ' ' does not usually mark a line ending.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that. But I think I should't have segmentation fault, because I know (in this case) what I will recieve, that is for example a filename like "image.jpg\n", in this case the array that I'm using is fname[50] (I know that's not totally correct). Should it give the error the same way?